# Returning static/ normal arrays in recursion/another function

Tags: c++, c, arrays, recursion, vector

A non-static array is declared in one function, it is returned and stored in another non-static array in main.

Q 1> I know that when an array is passed, it is passed by pointer(not by reference) so any changes made to the array in the passed function gets reflected in the original function but in this case while returning that array to another function say main shouldn't the original array be destroyed when it goes out of it's function scope?

> Static variable retain value within function calls and it's lifetime is the entire program so it is justified for a static array but why so for a non static array?

Q 2>Now say we have a non-static array declared inside a function that undergoes recursion, does the array gets declared each time it recurses? It doesn't goes out of the scope so the array is re-declared so why doesn't it gives a redeclaration error? Is it a new array or does the array gets over-written?

Say we have a static array now, it being a static it is declared only once..

> Does changes made in the array in one recursion gets reflected in another recursion if the array is static/non static?

I tried it out and I got that for non static arrays changes are not reflected but in static arrays the changes are reflected so again it basically boils down to the first question?

Q 3> Say we declared a static array and we run two tests(one imp thing to mention is we need the values we get in the previous recursion for the next recursion), the arrays values stored in the first test case(it being static) leads to incorrect values stored during the second test case run(well consider it as a vector so it will give incorrect output when we push the elements in second run since the values stored in the first run are already in the vector). Can you suggest a way to get around this w/o removing the static array

> > I know I have asked many questions all together at the same time, but I did that because they are all related 1 and 2 more so. 3 will help me clear my doubts better. It will be very helpful if you can clear the doubts. Thank You

Comment: To avoid possible misunderstandings it would be very helpful if you posted some sample code for each example to clarify your point.

Comment: I'd recommend to look up how the stack works in C. It's the easiest way to understand what static vs automatic really means.

Comment: Please choose one language, not two!

Comment: @BobbySacamano, it would be hard to look into 'how stack works in C', since there is no connection between the two.

Comment: @SergeyA saying 'how the stack works' is easier than saying 'how the LIFO data structure that manages function calls works'. Automatic variables are allocated within that data structure, and understanding how it works would answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q 1> I know that when an array is passed, it is passed by pointer(not by reference) so any changes made to the array in the passed function gets reflected in the original function but in this case while returning that array to another function say main shouldn't the original array be destroyed when it goes out of it's function scope?

Yes, the array will be destroyed when the function it's declared in exits. If you continue trying to use it after that point, you'll get "*undefined behaviour*" - which means that anything could happen. It might seem to work, it might crash, or it might contain garbage data.

> Q 2>Now say we have a non-static array declared inside a function that undergoes recursion, does the array gets declared each time it recurses? It doesn't goes out of the scope so the array is re-declared so why doesn't it gives a redeclaration error? Is it a new array or does the array gets over-written?

It's a new array. Each call to a function gets its own copy of that function's local variables.

> Q 3> Say we declared a static array and we run two tests(one imp thing to mention is we need the values we get in the previous recursion for the next recursion), the arrays values stored in the first test case(it being static) leads to incorrect values stored during the second test case run(well consider it as a vector so it will give incorrect output when we push the elements in second run since the values stored in the first run are already in the vector). Can you suggest a way to get around this w/o removing the static array

You could make it global, then clear it between tests. That's not the prettiest solution, but it's probably the easiest.